# Thunderbird: How to force use my pro email when sending emails to *@mycompany.com?

Tags: email, thunderbird

### Context

I have Thunderbird installed on my BYOD laptop. In Thunderbird, I have two accounts set up:

- private: `ebosi@gmail.com`,
- corporate: `ebosi@mycompany.com`

When I write a new message, I can choose the sender address: either my private or my corporate email. The default email is those of the account I'm currently checking the mailbox of.

### Problem

Sometimes, I'm checking my private mailbox and want to send a corporate email. But the default sender email is the `ebosi@gmail.com`. I usually change it manually to `ebosi@mycompany.com`… but I sometimes forgot. Which means I can potentially send confidential data through my private email.

### Question

**How to force Thunderbird to use `ebosi@mycompany.com`** (whatever the default preselected sender) **when I send emails to `*@mycompany.com` accounts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature does not currently exist in Thunderbird.  You will have to just *check* which sender you're using and set it to your company account so it uses your company's mail servers.

There's unfortunately no way around this currently (the only plugins I found for this are ancient and obsolete).  You could suggest this to the Thunderbird devs as a requested feature upstream [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Thunderbird&bug_severity=enhancement), but I don't know how successful you will be in getting this implemented any time soon.

---

Closest possible ThunderBird plugin would be https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/single-domain/?src=search but it won't automatically reset the sender, it just gives you a warning message.

Comment: Thanks! The issue is then now to be tracked in [Bug #1564828: Use my pro email only when sending emails to *@mycompany.com](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1564828)

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by Jorg K on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1564828#c2), **Thunderbird's [Single Domain add-on](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/single-domain/)** kind of does what I want.

Here is how it works:

1. You set a domain name (e.g. `mycompany.com`);
2. **You get a warning each time you want to send a message "across the domain boundary"**, that is:

   - inside-to-outside: from `ebosi@mycompany.com` to any email addresses that are not `@mycompany.com` (e.g. `ebosi@gmail.com`, `john.doe@anotherbigcorp.com`, …),
   - outside-to-inside from `ebosi@gmail.com` to any `@mycompany.com` email address.

And you don't get any warning if you send emails from `ebosi@gmail.com` to `john.doe@anotherbigcorp.com` (outside-to-outside), or from `ebosi@mycompany.com` to `jane.deo@mycompany.com` (inside-to-inside).

It is not a perfect answer, because I would ideally like to set multiple domain names (e.g. `@mycompany.com`, `@mycompany.io`, `@ourclient.com`) as the boundary, yet it still a great improvement!